# nesting multiple filter methods javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, foreach

i am trying to complete a challenge and im stuck:
i have one big **movies** array which has inside a propery **genreName** which is another array. I want to filter this **movies** by checking its **genreName** against selected genres from checkboxes stored in an array **selectedGenres**
My difficulties appear here, when i have to check each **genreName**  array against **all** elements in **selectedGenres**. The task is, if there are multiple genres in **selectedGenres** to only show **movies** that have **all** those selected genres, not just one of them.

code:

```
const movies = [ 
{title:"movie 1",genreName:["Action", "Drama"]},
{title:"movie 2",genreName:["Action", "Fantasy", "Adventure"]},
{title:"movie 3",genreName:["Action", "Fantasy", "Science Fiction"]},
{title:"movie 4",genreName:["Action", "Drama", "Thriller"]}
]
const selectedGenres = ["Action","Drama"];  //based on this selection, only movie1 and movie4 should be in the filteredMovies variable.

const filteredMovies = movies.filter(movie => { //loop through each movie
        movie.genreName.filter(genre => { // loop through each item in genreName array
          return selectedGenres.forEach(name => { // loop through each item in selectedGenres array
            return name.indexOf(genre) > -1;
          });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the movies and return `true` for movies that have [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) selected genre.

```js
const movies = [ 
{title:"movie 1",genreName:["Action", "Drama"]},
{title:"movie 2",genreName:["Action", "Fantasy", "Adventure"]},
{title:"movie 3",genreName:["Action", "Fantasy", "Science Fiction"]},
{title:"movie 4",genreName:["Action", "Drama", "Thriller"]}
]
const selectedGenres = ["Action","Drama"];  //based on this selection, only movie1 and movie4 should be in the filteredMovies variable.


const filteredMovies = movies.filter(movie => selectedGenres.every(filter => movie.genreName.includes(filter)))

console.log(filteredMovies);
```

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for `every`

```js
const movies = [
    {title:"movie 1",genreName:["Action", "Drama"]},
    {title:"movie 2",genreName:["Action", "Fantasy", "Adventure"]},
    {title:"movie 3",genreName:["Action", "Fantasy", "Science Fiction"]},
    {title:"movie 4",genreName:["Action", "Drama", "Thriller"]}
];

const filter = ['Action', 'Drama'];

const result = movies.filter(m => filter.length === m.genreName.length && m.genreName.every(g => filter.includes(g)));
console.log(result);
```